# Switch Images Based on external text file content

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying read a text file and based on the contents of that text file, change the image on a webpage. I tried using the console log to get error messages back, however I'm not getting errors. The contents of the txt file is literally the name of the images I want to show. Below is my javascript and html code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>

<script type="text/javascript">

window.onload = function(){

var txtFile = new XMLHttpRequest();
txtFile.open("GET", "../HTML/Images/Bowl.txt", true);
console.log(txtFile);
txtFile.onreadystatechange = function() {
    allText = txtFile.responseText;
  lines = txtFile.responseText.split("\n"); // Will separate each line into an array
    if (lines === 'GDogbowl.png'){
        document.getElementById('myImage').src='../HTML/Images/GDogbowl.png'
        }
    else if (lines === 'YDogbowl.png') {
        document.getElementById('myImage').src='../HTML/Images/YDogbowl.png'
        }
    else {
        document.getElementById('myImage').src='../HTML/Images/RDogbowl.png'
           }
     }
 }
   </script>
<body>
    <table class="centerTable" >
      <tr>
        <td>
          <div class="imgContainer">

            <div>
                        <img id="fullsize" />
                        <ul id="thumbs">
                        <img id="myImage" src= "../HTML/Images/RDogbowl.png" style="width:100px">
                        </ul>
            </div>
        <div class="imgButton">
        <button id="Bowl" >Toggle Color</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </td>
    </table>
</body>
```

Comment: after split, lines is an array where each element contains a line. So use, lines[0] to access the first element, lines[1] to access the second and so on..  If you have multiple items, you need to create a loop.

Comment: Oooh that makes sense, I only have one item so that works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

You can't magicly pull data out of an array as if it were a string. To solve the issue, you'll have to loop through the array after you've split the lines. Something like this:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
var data = null;

xhr.open("GET", "../HTML/Images/Bowl.txt", true);
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
        data = xhr.responseText.split('\n');

        for(var i=0; i<data.length; i++){
            document.getElementById('myImage').src='../HTML/Images/'+data;
        }
    }
};
xhr.send();
```

Comment: It's only one line in the text file.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check for `txtFile.readyState == 4` and `txtFile.status == 200` in your `readystatechange` handler, and you also need to do `txtFile.send()`.

You also need to reference each URL in the `lines` array separately. Here's an example with two ways to show the images:

```
var txtFile = new XMLHttpRequest();
txtFile.open("GET", "../HTML/Images/Bowl.txt", true);
console.log(txtFile);
txtFile.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (txtFile.readyState == 4 && txtFile.status == 200) {
    allText = txtFile.responseText;
    lines = txtFile.responseText.split("\n"); // Will separate each line into an array
    if (lines[0] === 'GDogbowl.png'){
      document.getElementById('myImage').src='../HTML/Images/GDogbowl.png'
    }
    else if (lines[0] === 'YDogbowl.png') {
      document.getElementById('myImage').src='../HTML/Images/YDogbowl.png'
    }
    else {
      document.getElementById('myImage').src='../HTML/Images/RDogbowl.png'
    }

    // if you have several images, you need several image elements:
    lines.forEach(function(imgUrl, i) {
      var image = document.createElement("img");
      img.src = imgUrl;
      img.id = "myImage_" + i;
      document.body.appendChild(img);
    });
  }
}
txtFile.send();
```

Comment: You have the exact name of the image file available to you. No need for all the if / else statements. Keeping it like this would mean rewriting the code everytime a new image is added or removed from the txt file. So it's a flawed design. Might want to improve that in your answer

Comment: The code sample I gave is meant to be edited down; I don't know what the OP is trying to do specifically.

Comment: now that I added the txtFile.send() I get an error on the console stating "Can't find variable txtFile"

Comment: If you declared `txtFile` (i.e. `var txtFile`) inside a function, then you can't access it outside that function. You'll need to call `txtFile.send()` in the same scope as the variable `var txtFile`.

Answer (score 0):

split returns an array, where each element contains a line. So use, lines[0] to access the first element, lines[1] to access the second and so on.

If you don't care about handling state changes of your xmlHTTPRequest, then you can use the onload event, rather than onstatechange. ( I think all modern browsers should support this by now)

And as others have alluded in their answers, if you only care about the first line item, and you are sure that the name in the file is always valid, then you can concatenate the strings to achieve your goal without all the if/else cases.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>

<script type="text/javascript">

window.onload = function(){

var txtFile = new XMLHttpRequest();
txtFile.open("GET", "../HTML/Images/Bowl.txt", true);
console.log(txtFile);
txtFile.onload = function() {
allText = txtFile.responseText;
lines = txtFile.responseText.split("\n"); // Will separate each line into an array
document.getElementById('myImage').src="../HTML/Images/"+lines[0];

</script>
<body>
<table class="centerTable" >
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div class="imgContainer">

        <div>
                    <img id="fullsize" />
                    <ul id="thumbs">
                    <img id="myImage" src="../HTML/Images/RDogbowl.png" style="width:100px">
                    </ul>
        </div>
    <div class="imgButton">
    <button id="Bowl" >Toggle Color</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </td>
</table>
</body>
```